# How to build a project on github with pom.xml

Tags: java, github, maven-2

This might be a naive question, so pardon me but I am new to maven.
I want to build a jar of project present on github. The project has a pom.xml file and additionally mentions in
Installation Note: 
Releases are distributed on Maven central:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>some_grp_id</groupId>
  <artifactId>all</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.2</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Am I suppose to add above in the existing pom.xml file ?? 
I an cloning the project on my desktop and then executing "mvn package".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply use the library then you only have to add the above dependency to your `pom.xml`. Maven is doing all the rest for you (downloading the `.jar`-file).

If you really want to use the source code you have to do a

```
mvn install
```

on the checked out code. And also have to include the dependency in your own `pom.xml`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me try that